# Oracle ORA-00905: Missing Keyword - Select from

Tags: sql, oracle

I am getting a keyword error for this sql. i dont know which part went wrong. i been trying to figure
the problem since morning.
This query is to get the latest information of subscribers from multiple table. any help would be appreciated

```
SELECT
    g.msisdn, c.name3, c.id_number,
    decode(g.sub_state, 'B01', 'Active', 'B02', 'Close', 'B03', 'Suspend','B02', 'Barring') STATUS,
    decode(g.prepaid_flag, '0', 'Prepaid', '1', 'Postpaid','3', 'Hybrid') RATING,
    d.offer_name, t.create_date
FROM inf_subscriber_all g
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT a.*, RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY cust_id ORDER BY create_date) rn
    FROM his_offers
) as a ON a.cust_id = g.cust_id AND a.rn = 1
INNER JOIN inf_customer_all c ON c.cust_id = a.cust_id
INNER JOIN pdm_offer d ON d.offer_id = a.offer_id
WHERE g.msisdn IN ('135018013','197745505','195154724')
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `as` from `) as a ON`. It should be just `) a ON`

Comment: removed 'as', getting a new error.. a is invalid identifier

Comment: @SimChengKeng In the inner query you have `select a.* from his_offers`. There's no `a` in that subquery. It should be something like `select h.* from his_offers h`.

Comment: @SimChengKeng also `t.create_date` should probably be `a.create_date`. I don't see anything labelled `t`.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson, thank you so much for your help. didnt notice the t was there. i modified the script and added the keyword to inner query, somehow the keyword error still appeared. no sure which part is triggering the error

Comment: `SELECT
    g.msisdn, c.name3, c.id_number,
    decode(g.sub_state, 'B01', 'Active', 'B02', 'Close', 'B03', 'Suspend','B02', 'Barring') STATUS,
    decode(g.prepaid_flag, '0', 'Prepaid', '1', 'Postpaid','3', 'Hybrid') RATING,
    d.offer_name, g.create_date
FROM inf_subscriber_all g
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT h.*, RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY h.cust_id ORDER BY h.create_date) rn
    FROM his_offers h
) as a ON a.cust_id = g.cust_id AND a.rn = 1
INNER JOIN inf_customer_all c ON c.cust_id = a.cust_id
INNER JOIN pdm_offer d ON d.offer_id = a.offer_id
WHERE g.msisdn IN ('135018013')`

Comment: I still see an `as a` in there.